# Rounding up to the nearest $5

Tags: rounding, powerquery, m

I am looking to round up prices to the nearest $5 after a price increase of 3%

I have tried the formula below

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "NewPrice", each Number.Round([Price]*1.03,0,RoundingMode.Up))
```

So a new price 0f $121 or $124, should come up as $125. Basically, I would like to re-create the Excel formula ceiling(Price*1.03,5)

Answer (score 2):

To round up to the nearest multiple of 5, you need to divide the value by 5, then round up to the nearest whole number, then multiply by 5 again.

Using `Number.RoundUp` instead of `Number.Round` is more efficient.

Applying these steps to your code, gives:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "NewPrice", each Number.RoundUp([Price]*1.03/5)*5, type number)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23446021)

Comment: Eh? Of course it provides an answer to the question!